# Why does `ipython foo.py bar.py` only print `foo.py`'s output?

Tags: ipython

The IPython 0.13.1 documentation says:

```
$ ipython -h
...
Usage

    ipython [subcommand] [options] [files]

    If invoked with no options, it executes all the files listed in sequence
    and exits, use -i to enter interactive mode after running the files.
...
```

I have two files `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

`foo.py`:

```
print "Hi, I'm foo."
```

`bar.py`:

```
print "Hi, I'm bar."
```

I expect the following to print both files output, in the corresponding order. Instead I only get the output from the first file given on the command line.

```
$ ipython foo.py bar.py
Hi, I'm foo.

$ ipython bar.py foo.py
Hi, I'm bar.
```

Is that an implementation bug, a documentation bug, or user misunderstanding? If the latter, what should I do instead?

Comment: I can confirm this as a bug, so it isn't a user misunderstanding.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the documentation. It doesn't (now?) run all the files, but behaves like you've called `python args`. So if foo.py looks at `sys.argv`, it will see bar.py listed there as a command line argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation failure, fixed by [this Pull Request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3073).
The command

```
$> ipython [-i] script.py script2.py ...
```

behaves exactly the same as the command

```
$> python [-i] script.py script2.py ...
```

In that, script.py is run, with `sys.argv` of `['script.py', 'script2.py', '...']`,
and if `-i` is specified, it drops into an interactive session after running the script.